# PayUMoney Gateway Titanium Appcelerator Android Integration

Tags: android, titanium

I'm creating an app using **Titanium Appcelerator *Android***.  I'm trying to integrate **PayUMoney** payment gateway in my application.

But i couldn't find any support modules or Javascript code. 
Is there any possiblity to integrate ?

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: @shandle No i didnt get solution